# How to call generic method like Find, FindAll

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I an intermediate C# develop. I am trying to implement some methods in my program. But it's been giving sleepless nights. E.g 
NB: I already declared the class properties ahead.

```
Employee employe = new Employee(){
    ID = 111,
    Name = "Eric Trump",
    Gender = "Male",
    Salary = 900000
};
Employee employe2 = new Employee()
{
    ID = 112,
    Name = "Ayo",
    Gender = "Female",
    Salary = 8900
};

List<Employee> listemp = new List<Employee>();
listemp.Add(employe);
listemp.Add(employe2);
```

How to i use the `Find`, `FindAll()` or `FindLast()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by passing a [`Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=netframework-4.8) delegate to [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.8), [`FindLast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findlast?view=netframework-4.8) or [`FindAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=netframework-4.8) methods

```cs
List<Employee> listemp = new List<Employee>();
listemp.Add(employe);
listemp.Add(employe2);

var result = listemp.FindLast(e => e.ID == 112); //or listemp.Find(e => e.ID == 112)
```

`e => e.ID == 112` is called **lambda expression**, it's just a more convenient way to specify an anonymous delegate, you can find more details at [Delegates and lambdas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/delegates-lambdas)

Comment: Ok. What about the find() method too?

Comment: @GbolahanEfunkoya the same is true for `Find` method as well, it accepts the same predicate as an argument

Comment: thank you sir. i appreciate. Can we connect on social platform? Your handle. instagram, twitter etc.

Comment: @GbolahanEfunkoya welcome, you can approve an answer, if it solves your question and help others in future. Well, I think this platform is enough for programming-related questions:)

Answer (score 1):

Just use lambda-expressions:

```
List<string> lists = new List<string>()
{
    "1", "2", "3"
};
var all = lists.FindAll(s => s == "1");
```

[Read more about `Find all` here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findall?view=netframework-4.8)

**UPDATE:**

[Lambda-expression is a shorter way to represent anonymous methods.](https://medium.com/swlh/lambda-expression-a-quick-guide-edef77c7c044) So you can use them like that:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee(){
       Id = 111,
       Name = "Eric Trump",
       Gender = "Male",
       Salary = 900000
    },
    new Employee(){
        Id = 112,
        Name = "Ayo",
        Gender = "Female",
        Salary = 8900
    }
};

var findAll = employees.FindAll(s => s.Id == 111);
var findLast = employees.FindLast(s => s.Id == 111);
var find = employees.Find(s => s.Id == 111);
```